# What is best way to create multiple gradient views with different start and end points

Tags: ios, swift

In my Project I have multiple gradient views with different colours and different start and end points. Some of the gradient views also have shadows with corner radius.

For this reason I have created multiple view types for each gradient requirement. Each `GradiantView` used at multiple places.

Ex:

```
struct ApplyGradiantView {
    var GradiantLayer : CAGradientLayer?
    init(frame:CGRect,Colors:[CGColor],startPoint:CGPoint,endPoint:CGPoint) {
        GradiantLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        GradiantLayer?.colors = Colors
        GradiantLayer?.startPoint = startPoint
        GradiantLayer?.endPoint = endPoint
        GradiantLayer?.frame = frame
    }
}
```

And

```
class blueGradiantView : UIView {

    var gradiant1Colour = AppColor.gradiantColor1.cgColor
    var gradiant2Colour = AppColor.gradiantColor2.cgColor

    var renderOnese = false

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        if !renderOnese {
            ApplyCustomeView()
            renderOnese = true
        }
    }

    func ApplyCustomeView() {
        let GradiantLayer = ApplyGradiantView(frame: self.bounds, Colors: [gradiant1Colour,gradiant2Colour], startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), endPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.8, y: 1.0))
        if let gradiantLayer = GradiantLayer.GradiantLayer {
            self.layer.insertSublayer(gradiantLayer, at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
class RedGradiantView : UIView {
    var inerGradiantView = UIView()

    var gradiant1Colour = AppColor.gradiantColor3.cgColor
    var gradiant2Colour = AppColor.gradiantColor4.cgColor
    var renderOnese = false

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        if !renderOnese {
            ApplyCustomeView()
            //            renderOnese = true
        }
    }

    private func ApplyCustomeView() {
        inerGradiantView.frame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        self.insertSubview(inerGradiantView, at: 0)
        let GradiantLayer = ApplyGradiantView(frame: self.bounds, Colors: [gradiant1Colour,gradiant2Colour], startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), endPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.8, y: 1.0))
        if let gradiantLayer = GradiantLayer.GradiantLayer {
            inerGradiantView.layer.insertSublayer(gradiantLayer, at: 0)
        }
        inerGradiantView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        inerGradiantView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    }

}
```

And

```
class ShadowWithRedBluer : UIView {

    var inerGradiantView = UIView()

    var gradiant1Colour = AppColor.gradiantColor3.cgColor
    var gradiant2Colour = AppColor.gradiantColor4.cgColor
    var renderOnese = false

    private var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        if !renderOnese {
            ApplyCustomeView()
//            renderOnese = true
        }
    }

   private func ApplyCustomeView() {
        inerGradiantView.frame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 2, dy: 2)
        self.insertSubview(inerGradiantView, at: 0)
        let GradiantLayer = ApplyGradiantView(frame: self.bounds, Colors: [gradiant1Colour,gradiant2Colour], startPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), endPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.8, y: 1.0))
        if let gradiantLayer = GradiantLayer.GradiantLayer {
            inerGradiantView.layer.insertSublayer(gradiantLayer, at: 0)
        }
        inerGradiantView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        inerGradiantView.clipsToBounds = true

        self.layer.applySketchShadow(color: UIColor.black, alpha: 0.15, x: 0, y: 50, blur: 50, spread: 0)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }        
}

extension CALayer {
    func applySketchShadow(
        color: UIColor = .black,
        alpha: Float = 0.5,
        x: CGFloat = 0,
        y: CGFloat = 2,
        blur: CGFloat = 4,
        spread: CGFloat = 0)
    {
        shadowColor = color.cgColor
        shadowOpacity = alpha
        shadowOffset = CGSize(width: x, height: y)
        shadowRadius = blur / 2.0
        if spread == 0 {
            shadowPath = nil
        } else {
            let dx = -spread
            let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: dx, dy: dx)
            shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
class ShadowOnlyView : UIView {

    var renderOnese = false

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        if !renderOnese {
            ApplyCustomeView()
            //            renderOnese = true
        }
    }

    private func ApplyCustomeView() {
        self.layer.applySketchShadow(color: UIColor.black, alpha: 0.15, x: 0, y: 50, blur: 50, spread: 0)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }

}
```

How can I use Protocol oriented Programming and generics  to reduce duplicate Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask:

> How can I use Protocol oriented Programming and generics to reduce duplicate Code?

While I’ll show you examples below, the TL;DR answer is that instead of protocol-oriented programming and generics, you should stick with the object-oriented patterns of UIKit. You want to hook into the UIKit mechanisms, and POP and generics are going to introduce more problems than they’re worth.

So, I’d suggest a `GradientView` subclass of `UIView` that does all the gradient stuff. If you then want to reuse it with a standard set of colors (e.g. reuse a `RedGradientView` repeatedly and a `BlueGradientView` repeatedly, then define subclasses from `GradientView` which doesn’t re-implement the gradient stuff, but just updates the colors accordingly).

So I might define a `GradientView` like so:

```
@IBDesignable
class GradientView: UIView {
    // Inspectables

    @IBInspectable var startColor: UIColor = .white                { didSet { updateGradient() } }
    @IBInspectable var endColor:   UIColor = .blue                 { didSet { updateGradient() } }
    @IBInspectable var startPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0) { didSet { updateGradient() } }
    @IBInspectable var endPoint:   CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1) { didSet { updateGradient() } }

    // UIView gradient layers

    override static var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { return layer as! CAGradientLayer }

    // initialization methods

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        updateGradient()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        updateGradient()
    }
}

private extension GradientView {
    func updateGradient() {
        gradientLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = startPoint
        gradientLayer.endPoint = endPoint
    }
}
```

Note a few things about this:

- Instead of adding the gradient layer as a sublayer and updating it in `layoutSubviews`, I just define the [`layerClass`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622626-layerclass) of the view to be a `CAGradientLayer`, and then you don’t need to worry about `layoutSubviews`. This might seem like a minor observation, but if you ever animate the resizing of views, by using the `layerClass` approach above, the gradient is properly rendered mid-animation. If you use the `layoutSubviews` approach, you’ll get a jarring resizing of the gradient.
- I’ve made this `@IBDesignable`. You don’t need to do this, but it’s useful if you ever want to see this properly rendered in IB.
- Note that I avoided implementing custom `init` method. You really want to stay within the established `UIView` initializers (so that you can use these in storyboards, you don’t have to litter your code with non-standard initialization, etc.).
- A very minor observation, but I’d suggest always starting your properties and variables with lowercase letters (e.g., instead of `GradientLayer`, use `gradientLayer`). Likewise, I’d suggest always starting your class names with uppercase letters (e.g. instead of `blueGradiantView`, I’d call it `BlueGradiantView`).
- While I’ll show you what the various red and blue classes below, I’d advise against incorporating the actual names of colors in class names. You don’t really want to have to change class names if you change color themes. Lol.

  I’d also suggest that, if targeting iOS 11 and later, that you abandon the use of `AppColor` type and instead used named colors (which you can access both programmatically as well as directly in IB).

Anyway, if you really want a `BlueGradientView` type, it might look like:

```
@IBDesignable
class BlueGradientView: GradientView {
    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }
}

private extension BlueGradientView {
    func configure() {
        startColor = AppColor.gradientColor1
        endColor = AppColor.gradientColor2
    }
}
```

And likewise `RedGradientView`:

```
@IBDesignable
class RedGradientView: GradientView {
    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }
}

private extension RedGradientView {
    func configure() {
        startColor = AppColor.gradientColor3
        endColor = AppColor.gradientColor4
    }
}
```

And a `RoundedRedWithShadowGradientView`:

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedRedWithShadowGradientView: RedGradientView {
    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }
}

private extension RoundedRedWithShadowGradientView {
    func configure() {
        applyShadow()
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }
}
```

Where you might have an extension like so:

```
extension UIView {
    func applyShadow(color: UIColor = .black,
                     alpha: Float = 0.5,
                     shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2),
                     blur: CGFloat = 4)
    {
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = alpha
        layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
        layer.shadowRadius = blur / 2.0
    }
}
```

Note, I’d avoid using `shadowPath` if you can (it simplifies animations avoiding needing to implement `layoutSubviews`). But do whatever you want. But make sure the `shadowPath` approach is offering some important utility that you can’t just achieve with corner radius because you don’t want to have an unnecessarily fragile solution.

Now, I suspect you’re going to read all of this and say “but I want to use protocol-oriented patterns and generics”, but while those are great Swift features, you just shouldn’t fight UIKit’s inherently OOP design. Behind the scenes, UIKit is still Objective-C and Swift-only patterns will not offer the interoperability that you really want. Perhaps as you shift to SwiftUI you can revisit this, but as long as you’re using UIKit, stick with the native OOP patterns of the UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach-1**

Instead of creating a `struct` for adding `gradient`, you can create an `extension` of `UIView` and create an `addGradient(colors:start:end:)` to it, i.e.

```
extension UIView {
    func addGradient(colors: [CGColor], start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = colors
        gradientLayer.startPoint = start
        gradientLayer.endPoint = end
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
self.view.addGradient(colors: [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor], start: .zero, end: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1))
```

**Approach-2**

In case you're doing it via `storyboard`, you can use `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` to change it via `storyboard` itself, i.e.

```
@IBDesignable
class DesignableView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var gradientColor1: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet{
            self.setGradient()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var gradientColor2: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet{
            self.setGradient()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var gradientStartPoint: CGPoint = .zero {
        didSet{
            self.setGradient()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var gradientEndPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1) {
        didSet{
            self.setGradient()
        }
    }

    private func setGradient()
    {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [self.gradientColor1.cgColor, self.gradientColor2.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = self.gradientStartPoint
        gradientLayer.endPoint = self.gradientEndPoint
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        if let topLayer = self.layer.sublayers?.first, topLayer is CAGradientLayer
        {
            topLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}
```

Simply set the `class` of `UIView` in `storyboard` as `DesignableView` and set the properties of `gradientColor1`, `gradientColor2`, `gradientStartPoint`, `gradientEndPoint`.

**Edit-1:**

You can create an `enum Gradient` and make multiple `cases` for `gradients` as per requirement, i.e.

```
enum Gradient {
    case blue(CGRect)
    case red(CGRect)

    var gradient: CAGradientLayer {
        switch self {
        case .blue(let frame):
            return self.gradient(colors: [.blue,.white], start: .zero, end: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1), frame: frame)
        case .red(let frame):
            return self.gradient(colors: [.red,.white], start: .zero, end: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0), frame: frame)
        }
    }

    func gradient(colors: [UIColor], start: CGPoint, end: CGPoint, frame: CGRect) -> CAGradientLayer {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = colors.map({$0.cgColor})
        gradientLayer.startPoint = start
        gradientLayer.endPoint = end
        gradientLayer.frame = frame
        return gradientLayer
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let gradient = Gradient.blue(view.bounds).gradient
self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

Comment: Hi @PGDev nice Solution.but I am using Those Gradient View at multiple Place.later if I want to Change Colour of  some Gradient I only need to Change at only one Place(specific GradiantView).In your Solution I have to Change At multiple Place.