# How do i make uiview using linear gradient in swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiview

i have in my figma this style: background: linear-gradient(155.98deg, #F5FEFF 0%, #C5F8FF 0%, rgba(106, 164, 189, 0.5) 47.57%, #0E8B9C 88.75%), #FFFFFF;
i need to make my uiview as linear-gradient

Comment: I’d generally subclass `UIView`, setting the `layerClass` to be a `CAGradientLayer`. That way you end up with a gradient view that gracefully responds to not only frame changes, but animation of those changes should you need it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56707989/1271826 for an example.

Comment: can you share a pic of your gradient in figma

Comment: You can see a general answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68238412/4227328)

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to configure a `CAGradientLayer` with an array of `colors` and `locations`. If you want a diagonal gradient, specify a `startPoint` and `endPoint`, too.

But you need to decipher that Figma CSS. The first parameter to `linear-gradient` is the angle. Linear gradients in iOS are not measured in angles, but rather with `startPoint` and `endPoint`, both of which are `CGPoint` references where `0, 0` represents the upper left corner of the view and `1, 1` represents the lower right corner. Your angle of `155.98deg` suggests that you're looking for a “from upper left to lower right” gradient, which would be a `startPoint` of `0, 0` and an `endPoint` of `1, 1`. (The exact mapping between the angle and these `CGPoint` values will vary based upon the aspect ratio of the view in question.)

The next parameter to `linear-gradient` is an array of tuples of colors and location. Solid colors are represented in hex strings. Translucent colors are represented with integer `rgb` values. So `#F5FEFF 0%` is at location 0.0 and a color of `0xf5` for red, `0xfe` for green, and `0xff` for blue. You need to divide all those numbers by 0xff (or 255). (The Xcode color literal will do that conversion for you.) And the 0% at the end of the string is the relative location of this color in the gradient (where 0% is the start of the gradient and 100% is the end). This correlates nicely to the `CAGradientLayer` property `locations` (though the % numbers are represented as values between `0` and `1`).

The `rgba(106, 164, 189, 0.5) 47.57%` is red, green, and blue values of 106, 164, and 189, respectively, (each divided by 255). The 0.5 is an alpha of 50%. And the 47.57 is the position (47.57% of the way along the gradient).

Anyway, to render this, define an array of colors, array of positions, and the start and end of the gradient:

```
@IBDesignable class GradientView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAGradientLayer.self }
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { layer as! CAGradientLayer }

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        gradientLayer.colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843137, green: 0.9960784314, blue: 1, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.7725490196, green: 0.9725490196, blue: 1, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.4156862745, green: 0.6431372549, blue: 0.7411764706, alpha: 0.5), #colorLiteral(red: 0.05490196078, green: 0.5450980392, blue: 0.6117647059, alpha: 1)].map { $0.cgColor }
        gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0, 0.4757, 0.8875]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
    }
}
```

If you want to see either the hex representation or integer representation of those colors, just double click on the color and tap on "Other" to see the RGB representations. E.g. I double clicked on the second color and I can see the `#C5F8FF` value:

[image]

A couple of final observations:

- Note, I didn't just add a `CAGradientLayer` and set its frame. Instead, I created a view whose backing layer is a gradient. That way, if the view size changes because of constraints (or if you animate the size change), the size of the `CAGradientLayer` changes dynamically, too.
- I made it `@IBDesignable` so I could see it in the storyboard. That’s not necessary, but is useful if using storyboards.
- I wonder if your designer really meant to have both `#F5FEFF` and `#C5F8FF` at the 0% position. I suspect that was a mistake. (Figma makes it too easy to have multiple color data points in the gradient overlap with each other at either 0% or 100%.)
- The CSS you've provided does not look syntactically correct. Notably, I don't know what to make of that `#FFFFFF` floating at the end (and your gradient points don’t go all the way to 100%). But, I don't think I need to know your full intent here ... you can just update the `CAGradientLayer` `colors` and `locations` arrays as you see fit. Just make sure they both have the same number of entries.
- As you have noted, if you tap on the rightmost “Code” tab in the panel on the right in Figma, you can see an iOS code snippet. I would be wary of using that code, verbatim, in your app, because it (a) won’t use the `UIView` subclass outlined above, breaking if the view changes size or is animated; and (b) it will tend to use hard-coded values whereas you generally want to use constraints to dictate the layouts within iOS. Use this code snippet for inspiration, suggestions of possible API, etc., but I would not be inclined to use that exact code. Like all auto-generated code snippets, Figma’s suggested iOS code is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```
let layerGradient = CAGradientLayer()
layerGradient.colors = [hexStringToUIColor(hex: "yourhex").cgColor,  hexStringToUIColor(hex: "yourhex").cgColor]
layerGradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
layerGradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
layerGradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: yourView.bounds.width, height: yourView.bounds.height)
self.yourView.layer.addSublayer(layerGradient)
```

Essentially you add a layer on top of your view which you then assign a start point and end point and provide colors to use.

This is the function used to convert hex strings to colors

```
func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()
    
    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }
    
    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }
    
    var rgbValue:UInt64 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
    
    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```